# WSAGetLastError return -1

Tags: sockets

I have a socket program, WSAGetLastError()  ==-1, I have try to find in msdn, but not found. Anyone known?I have a socket program, WSAGetLastError()  ==-1, I have try to find in msdn, but not found. Anyone known?

Comment: Show us some code please. Are you sure that is what the function is returning?

Comment: yes, i'm quite. i use android app,  my computer can't open stackoverflow, so not post code.

Comment: I don't know that WSAGetLastError can return -1 . The only thing I can think of is that you're reading it into a short / char instead of an int and the return value is therefore represented as a negative number.

Comment: WriteLog("%s : %d, SendType: %08x, RevType: %08x Error: %d, MS: %d",      __FILE__,__LINE__,pHeader->dwType, dwType, WSAGetLastError(),(GetTickCount()-m_dwTickCountLastSend)); follow is log: ServerSck.cpp : 265, SendType: 00000661, RevType: 80000600 Error: -1, MS: 0

Comment: What socket operation returned an error? Is this WriteLog line called immediately after? Is it receipt of an asynchronuous message?

Comment: after recv, not asynchronous.

Comment: Did `recv()` return -1? If it didn't, calling `WSAGetLastError()` isn't valid.